# Exporting NestJs module vs Exporting Providers

Tags: nestjs

The NestJs allows exporting modules and providers. What is the difference between them?

Example:

```
// Reusable module
@Module({
providers: [ServiceA],
exports: [ServiceA]
})
class ModuleA {}
```

When and where should this module be exported? What does it help in?

The NestJs documentation on [modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules) states the following...

> Now any module that imports the CatsModule has access to the CatsService and will share the same instance with all other modules that import it as well.

Comment: when you export the module, you're exporting every provider it exports.

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thanks for your response. 
Ex: If i import `ModuleA` in a `ModuleB` and import `ModuleB` in a `ModuleC`.
Won't the `ServiceA` be available for injection in `ModuleC`?

Comment: it will be as long as you have `exports: [ModuleA]` in your `ModuleB` setup.

Comment: Ok i think the nest js documentation is not very clear about this as i mentioned in the edited question. Please consider adding as an answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Exemple: To use a serviceA exported by a module A in another serviceB which is exported by another moduleB you must import the moduleA which exports the serviceA in moduleB

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question is when does exporting a module come into picture?

Comment: Sorry but the answer is here https://docs.nestjs.com/modules

Comment: sometimes you use dynamic modules and they could register providers dynamically (like the `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` one). If you want to use the provider they have in another module, you'll need to re-export the `TypeOrmModule`, otherwise you'll need to find out what are the tokens that that mode has created dynamically.